# 403 Forbidden after changing permission of files and folders

Tags: php, linux, magento, file-permissions

Magento officially recommends to set the permission of all folders to 700 and of files to 600. ([Source](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/Installing-a-Patch-for-Magento-Community-Edition.pdf?_ga=2.102153157.577489622.1539856323-1063748715.1529417426))

They instruct us to execute these commands to set the permissions:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

However, now I get 403 forbidden when I try to access the site.

Should I change it to 766 (folders) and 666 (files) instead?

Comment: huh weird, I'd always recommend `755` for `-type d` and `644` for `-type f` - what's the file ownerships?

Comment: the ownership is set to `root:root`

Comment: should ownership not be apache user / your user?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I tried `find . -print0 | xargs -0 chown wwwrun:root` but then the site does render weird.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it works with 755 for -type d and 644 for -type f like you recommended :)

Comment: yeah 755 and 644 are my go-tos in all of my projects :) but glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends very much on the configuration of your system.

When you are setting all permissions with the command of your question, executed as root, you are allowing only the root user to access these files.

The permission mask reads as follows:

```
000
^^^
|||
||+--- Other
|+---- Group
+----- Owner
```

So a permission mask of `600` with a root ownership wouldn't let the webserver's user (or php process' user) to read or access those files.

The first step would be to find out ther user that's running your webserver (Apache, Nginx, or whatever you are using), and the user assigned to your php process (in case you are using something like php-fpm).

If you are on an Ubuntu system, more likely than not that user is `www-data`. But you should make sure, since the details are configuration dependent.

Assuming the user you got is `www-data`, you go to the directory where you were runnig the `chmod` and change all the files so they are owned by this user:

```
chown -R www-data: {.??,}*
```

Later you apply the permissions from your question, and it should work.

#### Note: This is probably not how *I* would set up an installation, security wise, but that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: What is the `{.??,}*` part doing?

Comment: @Black That's to catch files that start with a `.` along with the rest. Otherwise you wouldn't affect files like `.htaccess`

Comment: I can't accept your solution until I tested it, but It looks correct.

Answer (score -1):

**You should change the ownership like this:**

```
sudo adduser <username> www-data
sudo usermod -a -G <username> www-data
sudo chown :www-data /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+rwX /var/www -R
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Also set magento required permission to files and folder

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod 550 mage
```

Hope these help.